extension therorem in fractional Sobolev spaces
I am recently reading papers regarding time-fractional pdes, and I am particular confused by a condition mentioned in the proof. Here are my questions.
In the proof, the first sentence states that:
For $g\in W^{s,p}(0,T;L^2(\Omega)),s\in [0,1/p)$ and $p\in(1,\infty)$. Extending $g$ to be zero on $\Omega\times [(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)]$ yields that $g\in W^{s,p}(\mathbb{R},L^2(\Omega))$.
Why the condition $s<1/p$ is needed? I wonder if this is a condition in the extension theorem, but I couldn't find it anywhere. Is there any reference in this?

Here you don't need extension theorems, since the extension is explicit. You just have to verify that the extension is in $W^{s,p}$. This could be done in different ways, depending on the definition of $W^{s,p}$ you are using. The main point here is that for $s<1/p$, functions in $W^{s,p}$ are allowed to have jump discontinuities, so extending the function as zero outside $[0,T]$ is fine and does not make the Sobolev norm infinite. By contrast, no function in $W^{s,p}$ with $s>1/p$ can have jump discontinuities, in fact all such functions are continuous.

In any case, you don't need the condition $s<1/p$ in extension theorems. It's just that when this condition is satisfied, you can simply extend the function as zero outside the domain, so the extension is easy. For larger $s$, the proof of the extension theorem is harder. By the way, note also that the condition $s>1/p$ is the same needed for trace theorems. That is, for such $s$ it makes sense to consider the restriction of the function to a hypersurface (in one dimension, a hypersurface is just a point, so for $s>1/p$ the function has to be defined at all points, so no jumps are allowed).
